# Get value of TemplateFields in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with getting value of template field; Gridview is in ContentPlaceHolder1;

I'm trying to get value in GridView1_RowCreated event

```
int RowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Text = " " + AltKatLinkler;
```

But this code returns me null or empty.

There is my column, column index is 0.
Note: I fill GridView by using SqlDataSource. There is no problem i can see row content in browser but i cant access from codebehind.

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="Haberler" sortexpression="KategoriID" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
    <ItemTemplate>
       < a href='<%# "KategoriGoster.aspx?KategoriID=" + Eval("KategoriID")%>'>
       <%# Eval("KategoriAd")%>
       <%# Eval("Açıklama")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: think you should try rowdatabound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see another way to do it

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="Haberler" sortexpression="KategoriID" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
    <ItemTemplate>
       < a href='<%# "KategoriGoster.aspx?KategoriID=" + Eval("KategoriID")%>'>
       <asp:Label ID="lbKategori" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KategoriAd").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
       <asp:Label ID="lbAçıklama" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Açıklama").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Codebehind

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            var lbKategori = e.Row.FindControl("lbKategori") as Label;
            var lbAçıklama = e.Row.FindControl("lbAçıklama") as Label;
        }
    }
```